# How can I make a Wordpress page override an existing directory (not sub-directory)?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, url-rewriting, slug

I have an existing directory called /final-fantasy-vii/ which has an /images/ folder inside of it. I created a page with the same slug of "final-fantasy-vii" and when I go to access that page online, it shows me the /images/ folder instead of the actual page I created in WordPress.

Is there a way around this? I've been cracking away at it for a couple of days now and I just can't figure out how to do it. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the slug (can be done while editing page, near the top in the middle of the page) or change the pre-existing directory. The slug doesn't have to be an exact match with the title so your best option is probably to just tweak that to something different that still makes sense for the content.

Comment: Is it not better for SEO though if the slug matches the page title exactly?

Comment: There's no science to SEO. It's definitely an art. As long as your slug matches (doesn't mean an exact duplicate), you should still reap whatever benefits you would have with the default slug.

Comment: To be honest, the only difference between what I wanted to have as my slug and the alternative is roman numerals vs numbers. I could easily switch the vii to a 7, but I just wasn't sure if that would be appropriate for search engines. So I should be good to go then, right?

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely be alright using the number. Google is really the only search engine you need to be worried about (and to a much lesser extent, Bing) and both pay attention to much more than the slug when determining content. Honestly, you actually might be **better** with the number since it's less ambiguous for the bots, though no one really knows for sure what they look for to that level of detail.